# How to get the login user through Rally App SDK

Tags: javascript, rally

I created a custom html inside the Rally page using its [App SDK](http://developer.help.rallydev.com/app-sdk). Now I want to get the username of the current login user. But I cannot figure out how to do that.

I noticed Rally provides some [Hangman Variables](http://developer.help.rallydev.com/hangman-variables) and current user name is one of them. But it seems it is only meaningful when we pass it as the parameter of some Rally API. However, I need to get the user name and use it in my javascript code.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hangman variables are treated as simple search and replaces by the server when serving up your app so you can put them anywhere in the source.

```
var user = "__USER_NAME__";
```

When your app runs the source would look like this:

```
var user = "vamcily";
```

In SDK 2.0 these hangmans are still available but are deprecated.  You can get information about the current user through the app context:

```
this.getContext().getUser();
```

Comment: What does "this" implies here? Which object does it refer to?

Comment: Sorry- this would be inside your app which extends Rally.app.App.  You can also use Rally.environment.getContext().getUser();